# $("...")[0].reset is not a function... resetting forms in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

I'm trying to reset some forms with jQuery but I'm having some trouble.  Aside from solutions that involve writing functions or custom plugins, I keep finding time and again that the reset method is not a standard part of jQuery but it is a part of standard Javascript.

Anyway, my first approach was to go with

`$("#theForm").reset();`

where the form's id="theForm".

That didn't work obviously, because it assumed that reset() was a part of jQuery.

The next thing I tried was

`document.getElementById(theForm).reset();`

Which didn't work either.  I'm new to jQuery so I'm not sure if I can mix normal Javascript with jQuery.  I must sound like a moron for saying this.

Anyway, After doing some more researching I found time and again that I could use reset() in jQuery by doing these...

`$("#theForm")[0].reset();`

or

`$("#theForm").get(0).reset();`

In every article that involves these two snippets everyone in the comments had gotten it working.

Except me.

The error console keeps telling me that what I have written does not exist.  I have checked all of my code and there is no other instance of the word "reset", so it can't be that either.

Anyway, I'm stumped.

Comment: Post the form, there's nothing wrong with the javascript (at least some of them).

Answer (score 46):

## Solution to original issue in this thread

For an HTML form like this:

```
<form id="theForm">
</form>
```

When using `document.getElementById("theForm").reset()`, if you are getting a js error saying

> reset() is not a function

the reason might be an element which has `reset` as `name` or `id`. I faced same issue.
Naming any element as `reset` overrides reset() function.

Comment: Great. I was using `<input type="button" value = "Clear Form" id = "reset" /> ` changing it to `<input type="button" value = "Clear Form" id = "formReset" /> ` worked :)

Comment: nothing called reset in my whole page code..

Answer (score 19):

This:

```
$("#theForm")[0].reset();
```

works just fine. Watch it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ99a/1/

So, there has to be something wrong either with the form, or with the way you are attaching the script to the button.

Comment: The form looks like this.  `<input type="text" id="theForm">`  Will the fact that this and other forms are all under a single <form> tag affect the reset?

Comment: Uh? The id goes in the form, not the input. I think you are mixing the "form" and "input" concepts.

Comment: I have multiple inputs under a single form tag.  But for some reason if I make them all individual form tags then it works very strangely.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. See updated Fiddle. By the way, why don't you post the relevant code there, so we can see it fails? So far, we're guessing.

Answer (score 6):

The error is caused by giving the reset button (or any other form element) the name reset -- `name="reset"`. Thus `form.reset` resolves to the DOM element with `name="reset"` and not the reset method.

**DEMO WITH `name="reset"` - check console**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.reset1').on('click', function() {
        this.form.reset();
    });
  
    $('.reset2').on('click', function() {
        $('form')[0].reset();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="somename"/><br/>
  <input type="button" name="reset" class="reset1" value="Reset - form.reset()"/><br>
  <input type="button" name="reset" class="reset2" value="Reset - $('form')[0].reset()"/>
</form>
```

**SAME DEMO BUT WITH `name!="reset"` - no error; code works**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.reset1').on('click', function() {
        this.form.reset();
    });
  
    $('.reset2').on('click', function() {
        $('form')[0].reset();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="somename"/><br/>
  <input type="button" name="someothername" class="reset1" value="Reset - form.reset()"/><br>
  <input type="button" name="someothername" class="reset2" value="Reset - $('form')[0].reset()"/>
</form>
```

**SAME DEMO BUT WITH `id="reset"` - check console**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.reset1').on('click', function() {
        this.form.reset();
    });
  
    $('.reset2').on('click', function() {
        $('form')[0].reset();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="somename"/><br/>
  <input type="button" id="reset" class="reset1" value="Reset - form.reset()"/><br>
  <input type="button" id="reset" class="reset2" value="Reset - $('form')[0].reset()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't tell who you're and I don't if you're the same person that's on a roll. **When you downvote a post please give a reason, and especially if it's after so long! Otherwise we have a hard time not thinking that you're being malicious. :(**

Answer (score 2):

if `"theForm"` is an ID, do we need to use `$('#theForm')[0]` ?
I think it is a wrong habit.
If there are more forms in an HTML page, use names. And if you use ID, it should be unique.

It would be great if you can provide your HTML code here :)

Answer (score 0):

So... I think there are a few things going on here.

1. As Diego pointed out in his answer, `$('#theForm')[0].reset();` works very well.
2. The second example you tried:  `document.getElementById(theForm).reset();` won't work because javascript is going to think that you're using a variable called "theForm" -- if that were the case then the variable's value would have to be the string representing the id of your form... something like `var theForm = 'theForm';` and that can get really confusing really fast.  I suspect what you meant to try was:  `document.getElementById('theForm').reset();` -- which works swimmingly and is basically the same thing as the code from #1.
3. These examples are all assuming that your HTML is something like:  `<form id="theForm"> ... </form>` -- the id "theForm" must be on the form tag, not on an input tag within the form.

I've created a fiddle that shows these things working:  http://jsfiddle.net/boliver/ZDQxE/

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you don't have a form element named 'reset'. If so, rename it and .reset() method will be working. Otherwise document.getElementById("formId").reset will select form element with name 'reset', that's why reset() method can't be working. Yo will get error message like 'object is not a function'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the form's reset button id is set to "reset", thus the error message.

I had the same problem and then finally figured out and changed my form to:

```
    form action="bla" method="post" id="myform">
    ...
    
    /form>
```

Changing the reset button id did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#formData')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me until I changed the

```
<div class="form" id="myForm">...</div>
```

to

```
<form class="form" id="myForm">...</form>
```

Now both of these methods work in my javascript code:

```
$('#myForm').get(0).reset();
```

and

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```